# Not able to access images folder inside a module

Tags: orchardcms

I have an Images folder inside my module. I have added a web.config to this folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Script,Read">
      <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In the view file, I tried using img src=../Images/background.png, and full path resolves to this,
localhost:4126/OrchardLocal/Contents/Item/Images/background.png.

I tried to use this absolute url for image src, localhost:4126/OrchardLocal/ModuleName/Images/background.png, it still didn't work. I get the 404 error.

How to get this working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never use a relative path from a view, as this won't be resolved server-side but client-side, relative to the current path and not to your view file. You can use `@Href("~/Modules/ModuleName/Images/background.png")` instead, which will get resolved server-side correctly.